# HTTP POST-Request in Swift for login returns "MISSING_USERNAME" in response

Tags: swift, api, http

I'm setting up a Login screen for my app and only get a negative response as:

> "MISSING_USERNAME"

from the API on login.

I use two text fields "username" and "password", and also a "Login" button which triggers the login function where the POST-request is defined.

```swift
import Foundation
import UIKit

class Login: UIViewController {

    //Textfields
    @IBOutlet weak var Username: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var Password: UITextField!

    //Login Button
    @IBAction func LoginAction(_ sender: Any) {

        //POST request
        var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://[here address of API]]")!)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        let postString = "username=\(Username.text!)&password=\(Password.text!)"
        request.httpBody = postString.data(using: .utf8)
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
            guard let data = data, error == nil else {
                print("error=\(String(describing: error))")
                return
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The POST-request goes through, but comes back with a negative response:

> "responseString = Optional("{\"success\":false,\"error\":\"Username
>   required.\",\"code\":\"MISSING_USERNAME\"}")"

Even though my credentials are right (tested it out on the actual website and in insomnia) I always get the response above.
What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Is your API expecting a header with the content type, ie application/x-www-form-urlencoded ?

Comment: As a side note, convention in Swift is to use camel case for variables and function names, e.g. lowercase first letter.

Comment: just looked it up, content type is "application/json"

Comment: In that case your API request isn’t formatted correctly. Encode the body as JSON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for helping.
I solved the problem simply by encoding the body as JSON.